# How to export images into subdirectory in GIMP?

Tags: python, export, diacritics, subdirectory, gimp

I use GIMP for some batch editing, part of this is exporting painting with the filename taken from original image "filename" with this code:

```
pdb.file_png_save_defaults(ima, drawable, fullpath, filename)
```

At this moment, I have

```
fullpath=filename
```

so it saves the image into same folder as the source and filename and fullpath are identical.

What I want to do is to put it into subdirectory in this folder, lets call it `"subfolder"`. But if I try:

```
fullpath = '\subfolder\'+filename
```

I get an error, obviously, because I am working with Python (or any programming language) for like half an hour and I hardly know what I am doing. Does anybody know how to achieve exporting images into a subfolder?

UPDATE:

Now it looks like this

```
sourcename = pdb.gimp_image_get_filename(ima)
basedir = os.path.dirname(sourcename)

if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder')) is False:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder'))

fullpath = os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder',filename)
```

... and it works well. Almost. Now I am facing the problem with diacritics in basedir. When basedir contains something like "C:\Úklid\" I get "no such file or directory" error when code is creating Subdirecotry in it. After I rename the source folder to "C:\Uklid\" it works with ease. But I do need it to work with every path valid in Windows OS. Can someone help me with that?

**UPDATE 2:**

Looks like unicode() did the trick:

```
sourcename = pdb.gimp_image_get_filename(ima)
basedir = os.path.dirname(sourcename)

if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder')) is False:
    os.makedirs(unicode(os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder')))

fullpath = os.path.join(basedir,'Subfolder',filename)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: >>> fullpath = '\subfolder\'+filename
  File "<input>", line 1
    fullpath = '\subfolder\'+filename
                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You need the full path and you need forward slashes, e.g.: `fullpath = 'basedir/' + 'subfolder/' + filename`

Comment: So I can not save it just to the subfolder of the original file, I need to hardcode whole path?

Comment: Is `filename` a full path? If so you could do this: `import os; basedir= os.path.dirname(filename); fullpath = os.path.join(basedir,'subfolder',filename)`

Comment: No, I recieve it from 'filename = pdb.gimp_layer_get_name(ima.layers[0])' so it's basically just XYZ.tiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import os

sourcename = pdb.gimp_image_get_filename(ima) # gets full name of source file
basedir= os.path.dirname(sourcename) # gets path
name = pdb.gimp_layer_get_name(ima.layers[0]) # gets name of active layer
filename = name+'.png'
fullpath = os.path.join(basedir,'subfolder',filename) # use os.path.join to build paths
# new line vvv
os.makedirs(os.path.join(basedir,'subfolder')) # make directory if it doesn't exist
drawable = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(ima)
pdb.file_png_save_defaults(ima, drawable, fullpath, filename) # saves output file
```

Comment: This is it! Works like a charm. I can not express how happy I am. Thank you very much!

Comment: Samozřejmě :-) Není zač!

Comment: Oh, wow. Any chance of helping me with converting this script into GIMP plugin? :D I googled a lot but still can not get it into my GIMP menu.

Comment: @JaroslavSpříjmením: I'm sorry to say I don't know anything about GIMP plugins... Přeju hodně štěstí.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out. Anyway I found another complication with your code. There is "make directory if it doesn't exist" line in it. Problem is that when directory already exist, it generates huge error and whole script stops. Is there any way how to run this line only when directory does not already exist?

Comment: Good job for fixing it!